# Force ethernet adapter IP to be active even without cable plugged in

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

I have been working on some TCP communications in python and when it all of a sudden did not work I figured out that it was because I had unplugged the original device which were used to communicate with, because I just wanted to test it locally for faster response.

The communication is a Request->Reply pattern and the request client is supposed to connect to

192.168.50.11

which my ethernet adapter is configured to.

When no device is connected to my ethernet adapter "ipconfig" will show "Media Disconnected" on the ethernet adapter and when I connect the device it will show the correct IP 192.168.50.11.

Is there a way to keep the ethernet adapter "active" with nothing in the other end or do I have to write a checker function in python that switches to "localhost" when nothing is connected?

Thought: Could I just edit localhost to match my desired IP?

Comment: I can't think of a way to ping something when the Ethernet cable is disconnected - but have you tried using a static address? Set the nic to static then change the loopback address to 192.168.50.11

Comment: I already hav e set a static IP on my ethernet adapter under IPv4 if that is what you mean by nic

Comment: sorry, nic is network interface card! Can't think of any way other than when host down ping localhost.... Can you add a virtual interface and enable routing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Force ethernet adapter IP to be active even without cable plugged in

That won't work. When an interface is offline, any IP bound to it is offline as well.

The direct answer to your problem would be "use a loopback interface" - a loopback is always up and working, regardless of physical interfaces. However, a loopback requires proper routing and may be not trivial to implement.

What you really seem to need is to configure your server software to use `0.0.0.0`, the "unspecified address". Using that address binds to any and all local addresses, including `127.0.0.1` and any physical interface, even if it's currently down or when it's added to the system at a later time.

On the local client, you can use `127.0.0.1` as destination at any time, or `192.168.50.11` on a networked client (requires a link, obviously).